# Create tables by JOINing two tables using a third

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have three tables:

---

### TABLE 1 (7.7million records)

`ID_1|..|..| OTHER FIELDS|`

---

### TABLE 2 (8.2 million records)

`ID_2 |..|..|.....`

---

### TABLE 12 (7.5 million records)

`ID_1| ID_2 | SOMEFIELDS|`
AND `ID_1== ID_2.i.e.` contains all common `ids`

The `table 12` contains unique `ids` which are common to `table 1` and `2`. 
I am trying create a new table to get all data from `t1` and `t2` by matching which records in `t12` with `id_1,id_2`).

Following is the sql Iam using:

```
CREATE TABLE ARROW_all_common12 AS 
SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM T1, T2
LEFT JOIN T12 
ON T12.ID_1=T1.ID_1
LEFT JOIN T12
ON T12.ID_2 = T2.ID_2
WHERE T12.ID2 = T2.ID_2
```

Comment: @JNK This being an Oracle question, I'd suggest using INITCAP() :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but maybe a view could be what you're looking for?

```
CREATE VIEW someview AS (
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM table12 AS t12
    INNER JOIN table1 AS t1
        ON t1.id_1 = t12.id1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON t12.id_2 = t2.id_2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

same, it's not quite clear. maybe that?

```
create table t_all_12 as (
      select t1.*, t2.* 
      from t1, t2, t12
      where t12.id_1 = t1.id_1
      and t12.id_2 = t1.id_2
)
```

Comment: hey everyone.. thanks for your response. the question is that i was getting error on running that query.

well, i will not need a view as i have to use the data for further analysis. 

Let me try what has been suggested above and will update.